# Unexpected line on tab icon in tab bar

Tags: ios, tabbar

I want to use a larger than normal size image as an icon of tab bar, the image's height is higher than tab bar.

If I init the tab which icon is bigger in the initialization of tab bar, there's an unexpected line above the icon. The code like:

```
FirstViewController *FVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test75x75.png"];

FVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
[FVC.tabBarItem setImage:[image2 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
SVC.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks tag:2];

NSArray *array = @[FVC, SVC];
self.myTabbarController.viewControllers = array;

UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myTabbarController];
[self presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

As the screenshot, The line of tab bar is above the icon of FVC(The first tab in screenshot)

But if I add a new tab which has larger icon after the initialization of tab bar,
There's no line above the icon, see the third tab of screenshot.
The code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateTabbar) withObject:self afterDelay:2];
```

The method 'updateTabbar' adds the third tab into tab bar.

My question is: 
If I want to create tab(with larger icon image) in the initialization of tab bar, How can I hide the unexpected line above the icon?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
self.tabBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

For remove the line on the top of the tabBar.

Comment: Thank you. But this isn't what I want. This sentence make the icon smaller to fit into tab bar, but I want to keep the image original size(The image size is higher than tab bar's height).

Comment: @abentotoro: put the image with exact size and adjust.

Comment: Hi Vineesh TP, Sorry, I didn't get what you mean. The first tab image's size is same as the third image's size, but there's no unexpected line above the third image.